# Value in the submission form

Tags: css, forms

I've create a RSS submission form and I want to show in the input box something like `Enter your email here....`, and when they click on it that message should be disappear and they can put their email in the box.

Here is the code I'm using at the moment

```
<div id="RSS">
        <form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" class="RSS" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=RSS', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
            <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="RSS">
            <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US">
            <input name="email" id="RSS-text" type="text" maxlength="100" style="width:160px !important" value="Enter your email address..." class=""><button type="submit" id="RSS-button">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't disappear when someone click on it, and I saw many forms including my search form it can be done that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the placeholder attribute, but it doesn't support IE:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your text here..." />
```

Otherwise you can use a bit of javascript:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your text here...') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your text here...';" value="Enter your text here..." />
```